# am Run A task.delay async function but when i close form and open it again it still working?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, task

I am using `async` function with `task.delay`. I used it to calculate exam time but when i close the form and open it again task still ruing and  not closed and also using `cancellationtoken` also network

```
         //this call  to cancel 
        tokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokensource.Cancel();
        TimeUpdater(tokensource.Token); 

      //this call  to call function 

        TimeUpdater(new CancellationTokenSource().Token);

       async void TimeUpdater(CancellationToken token)
       {
        while (!IsPause && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            time.Text = Convertsecs(Staticsecs);
            // = $"{DateTime.Now.Subtract(_start).Hours.ToString()}:{DateTime.Now.Subtract(_start).Minutes.ToString()}:{DateTime.Now.Subtract(_start).Seconds.ToString()}";
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            Staticsecs++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"and also using cancellationtoken also not work"_ Do you call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`at some point? Please provide a [repro].

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed please check the code after update

Comment: This is still not a [repro] because we don't know how you declared `Staticsecs`, how you open and close the form, etc. Moreover, your code has a few problems. 1) you call `Cancel()` before actually calling the method? This way, the code inside your `while` loop will never be executed. 2) You're using an `async void` signature which makes your method non-awaitable. Consider using `async Task` instead.

Comment: On another note, unless this is some kind of assigment to practice using `async` and/or `Task.Delay`, you should consider using a timer instead; it's more suitable for this purpose. Look into [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) if this is a WinForms project or [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) otherwise.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed iam calling  cancel() before calling  in every  time iam opening form to close  the function if it exist

Comment: @HudaTwfik You are creating a new token and start a new TimeUpdater which immediately stops because of the token. You don’t stop an already running TimeUpdater because you for this you would need to cancel the token that you provided to the already running TimeUpdater. The correct order would be `tokenSource?.Cancel(); tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); TimeUpdater(tokenSource.Token);`. Never do `TimeUpdater(new CancellationTokenSource().Token);` because you can never access this CancellationTokenSource to cancel it, always do `TimeUpdater(tokenSource.Token);`.